# Python REPL in Django

Tags: python, django, read-eval-print-loop

I want to execute python code in my browser. Now I enter code in text-field in template, took it to view, where doing following:

```
source = request.POST.get('source', '').replace('"', r'\"')
result = commands.getoutput('python -c "%s"' % source)
```

I used python's module command for this, but I think it's don't correct way.
Correct way is using code module, but I don't understand how to get result of execution code and organise REPL. Can you give a little tip how to do it, please?

**UPD:** I want to start interactive shell in my browser with some variables. User can write some functions to manipulate this vars in browser and see that comes out of it. I understand the danger of this, but now it is not relevant.

Comment: You want to run the python code on your server after sending from the browser? Or you want to do everything in the browser?

Comment: You could use werkzeug which is able to do this kind of things.

Answer (score 0):

You need to take a look at [eval](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#eval) and [exec](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-exec-statement) also it is potentially very dangerous from [security](http://lybniz2.sourceforge.net/safeeval.html) point of view.